how can i remove a particular part from media urls in wordpress?
i want to remove https://bikinilite.com/wp-content/uploads/ from all the urls.
For example here is a full url https://bikinilite.com/wp-content/uploads/https:/ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6208578b32684d54a85671297433a582H.jpg so i want to remove the first part https://bikinilite.com/wp-content/uploads/ and the other part should stay. how can i do so? It's a wordpress website
I tried to gain this by applying some snippets but nothing works.

Where are all of these URLs that you need to fix? Are they in a database where you need to do a database update? Are they coming from another source where you need to update them live in a server-side script? If you know the length of the string that you need to remove (suggest 42), it should be possible to check that each string starts with the Bikini URL and to drop the first 42 characters.

If you have experience with the command line, use WP CLI. They have a wp search-replace command that you can use that should be able to scrub what you need: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/
If you want to use a plugin, use WP Migrate.
In both cases, you can use their search / replace tools to find strings in your database and replace (or remove) them.
Word of warning: DO NOT use this directly in Production without making backups or knowing what you're doing. If you're carelessly scrubbing your database in place without testing locally or any kind of backup process, you risk damaging your data, so be careful.
